# Htaccess second rewrite rule not working on Production

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The weirdest thing. Both rewrite rules are working on our Test server but the second one `locations` is not working on Production and adds a `/` at the end of `locations/` for some reason. The configuration is the same on both servers.

I am trying to simplify the URL without renaming the file. So that if the user enters `site.php/locations` it will load the content of the redirect page but retain the simplified URL

Any ideas as to why the `locations` redirect is not working?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

// The next two are statements are just for context. They preceded the faq and locations forward 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]

// The two rewrites that I want
RewriteRule ^faq$ /faq-mailbox-account.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^locations$ /choose-digital-mailbox-location.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Something is missing here... `site.php/locations` will _obviously_ never get matched by `^locations$`. But the same holds true for the "faq" rule. So please take the time to revise your question. Explain your _real_ setup.

Comment: Forgot to include the RewriteBase. So the rewrite is supposed to match the text after: `site.php/`

Comment: Doesn't change a thing. The patterns cannot match.

Comment: Please make sure you are not looking at cached results from earlier attempts. In _both_ environments.

Comment: I revised my question. I'll ask my manager to look into the caching tomorrow since he handles the server stuff. 

Also note that it was only pushed to Prod once. and a few times on the Test server. and the `faq` redirect was working fine on all intstances just the `locations` one has the issue

Comment: Caching is usually performed on the client side. You can check that yourself easily. And you _always_ should do that when testing things in a web setup.

Comment: I will ask another suggestive question, because I have an idea what might be wrong with the question: can it be that "site.php" is meant to stand for a domain name / host name? So that you _actually_ mean `https://example.com/locations` when you write `site.php/locations`? Or do you _really_ mean a requested URL like `https://example.com/site.php/locations`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but yes I meant `https://example.com/site.php/locations`
Turn out the problem was due to a locations folder that existed on prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... on Production and adds a `/` at the end of `locations/` for some reason

This will happen if `locations` exists as a physical directory on the filesystem. (Or *existed* and the response was cached.)

If you request `/locations` and `/locations` exists as a physical directory then mod_dir will issue a 301 external redirect to append the trailing slash - ordinarily, this is necessary in order to "fix" the URL.

This external "redirect" by mod_dir will happen regardless of whether your rule matches or not<sup>***1**</sup>, since it is "only" an *internal rewrite* and not another redirect. (<sup>***1**</sup> In fact, it does match and the rewrite does occur, but it is effectively overridden by the mod_dir redirect.)

You could append an *optional* slash to your `RewriteRule` *pattern*, eg. `^locations/?$` - but the redirect will still occur first if you are requesting `/locations` without the trailing slash. You would need to request a URL that already contains the trailing slash.

You could prevent mod_dir from appending the trailing slash using `DirectorySlash Off`, however, this potentially has other implications for your system.

Note also, that since this is a 301 (permanent) redirect, it will likely be cached persistently by your browser. So, if the `/locations` directory has since been deleted on the server, the browser will still redirect the user until all client-side caches have been cleared also.

> The configuration is the same on both servers.

So, there is (or *was*) a `/locations` directory on both servers?

If the configuration is the same on both servers then you would get the same response, so there must be some difference. Or, there is a client-side caching issue.

> So that if the user enters `site.php/locations`

I assume you meant `site.com/locations` - otherwise, the directives you posted have no hope of working, as they simply won't match.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but yes the issue was because of a symbolically linked drive

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a symbolically linked drive on Prod